# Bizzare behaviour of which() function in R

Tags: r

The problem is *which()* function doesn't work properly. Bizzare problem occurs in R:

This code:

> percentile.range<-(seq(0.32,1,0.01))
>
> which(percentile.range==.59)

Returns:

> integer(0)

And

> percentile.range<-(seq(0.32,1,0.01))
>
> which(percentile.range==.61)

Returns

> 30

This is beyond me, how such a simple statement doesn't produce a desirable result? Did I miss anything?

Comment: `percentile.range[which(percentile.range>=.5899 & percentile.range<=.59001)]`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: That solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: I prefer this approach to compare 2 floating point numbers : `abs(percentile.range - 0.59) <= 1e-12 (or another tolerance value)`

Comment: Thanks @digEmAll that solves my problem. If you put it in the answer I will accept it.